# error in editing byte[] from images

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to do image processing on wp7,
and now i finished convertImagetoBytes and convertByteToBitmapImage.

I suppose I can change the values in the byte array to do some image processing work,
but it turns out to be a black image in the picturebox.
(Now I just wanna process .jpg images)

convertImagetoBytes

```
byte[] data = null;

using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    WriteableBitmap wBitmap = new WriteableBitmap(bitmapImage);
    wBitmap.SaveJpeg(stream, wBitmap.PixelWidth, wBitmap.PixelHeight, 0, 100);
    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    data = stream.GetBuffer();
}
```

convertBytestoImage

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
stream.Position = 0;
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
bi.SetSource(stream);
return bi;
```

now if i change the values in the byte array,just like this(grayscale)

```
for (int i = 0; i < bytesCount; i+=4)
{
     colorTemp = data[i+2];
     data[i+1 ] =data[i+2]= data[i + 3] = (byte)colorTemp;
}
```

the image turns out to be black.

Comment: Your line of colorTemp = data[i+2] seems odd - are you sure this is what you want, and doesn't actually overwrite black pixel data with black (and not greyscale as you intended)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also look into using [René Schulte's WriteableBitmapEx library](http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/).

And consider reading this article about a [Windows Phone Picture Effects Application](http://channel9.msdn.com/coding4fun/articles/PicFx--Windows-Phone-Picture-Effects-Application--Part-2)

Comment: i'm using writeablebitmap.pixels and wow,thanks for you recommendation

Answer (score 1):

You've saved it as a JPEG - but you appear to be trying to change it as if it were raw data. You can't just mess around with the data of a JPEG file to fake greyscale.

By the way, you should use `stream.ToArray` instead of `stream.GetBuffer()` as the latter will usually be larger than the real data.